# DBLookUpComboBox does not save the record in the database when selecting with ENTER - Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I made this code to search dblookupcombox that is on the screen and select the record with ENTER, it is selecting the record correctly, but it does not save the correct record in the database, it continues with the old one :( I did this code in the ApplicationEvents1Message

```
if (Screen.ActiveControl.ClassName ='TDBLookupComboBox') then
  begin
    if (Screen.ActiveControl is TDBLookupComboBox) then
    begin
      if (Msg.wParam = VK_RETURN) then
      begin
        (Screen.ActiveControl as TDBLookupComboBox).KeyValue := (Screen.ActiveControl as TDBLookupComboBox).ListSource.DataSet.FieldByName((Screen.ActiveControl as TDBLookupComboBox).KeyField).Value;
        (Screen.ActiveControl as TDBLookupComboBox).ListSource.DataSet.Locate((Screen.ActiveControl as TDBLookupComboBox).KeyField, (Screen.ActiveControl as TDBLookupComboBox).KeyValue, [loCaseInsensitive]);
      end;
    end;
  end;
```

Comment: What you mean with "it does not save the correct record in the database"? You dont have code in this source to save Dataset into database. What type of Datasets you use? What database?

Comment: I'm fetching cities from my database in firebird 2.5, I click on my dblookupcombobox and type in the city name, press ENTER it selects the city I typed, but when saved, it saves the old city and not the one I typed I selected with ENTER

Comment: "but when saved, it saves the old city"  In which dataset, the dataset which is the `listsource.dataset` or the one that contains the field used to look up the city?  In any case you need to add a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your q.

Comment: `Screen.ActiveControl` is simply wrong. It should just be `ActiveControl` or `Self.ActiveControl`.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a sample project which requires no external datafiles and illustrates the
use of a DBLookUpComboBox to select a CityName from its drop-down list and return the
related CityID to the CityID field of a Clients table.

As you'll see, most of the set-up is done in the FormCreate event handler, so that all necessary
setting of the TDBLookUpComboBox's properties (apart from its datasource) is done in explicit code.  Only
the Datasource property of the TDBGrid, TDBNavigator ant TDBLookUpComboBox needs to be set in
the Object Inspector.

Notice that the DBLookupComboBox1KeyDown handler is all that is required once an item has been
selected from the drop-down list to post the current record in the cdsClients table, updated
with the related CityID, back to the cdsClients table.

Code:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    DBGrid1: TDBGrid;            //  DataSource dsClients
    DBNavigator1: TDBNavigator;  //  DataSource dsClients
    dsClients: TDataSource;
    cdsClients: TClientDataSet;
    cdsCities: TClientDataSet;
    DBLookupComboBox1: TDBLookupComboBox;  //  DataSource dsClients
    dsCities: TDataSource;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure DBLookupComboBox1KeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
      Shift: TShiftState);
  public
  end;

[...]

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  AField : TField;
begin

  //  Set up the City look-up dataset first
  AField := TIntegerField.Create(Self);
  AField.FieldName := 'CityID';
  AField.DataSet := cdsCities;

  AField := TStringField.Create(Self);
  AField.FieldName := 'CityName';
  AField.DataSet := cdsCities;

  cdsCities.CreateDataSet;
  cdsCities.InsertRecord([1, 'New York']);
  cdsCities.InsertRecord([2, 'London']);
  cdsCities.InsertRecord([3, 'Paris']);

  //  Now, set up the Clients table
  AField := TIntegerField.Create(Self);
  AField.FieldName := 'ClientID';
  AField.DataSet := cdsClients;

  AField := TStringField.Create(Self);
  AField.FieldName := 'ClientName';
  AField.DataSet := cdsClients;

  AField := TIntegerField.Create(Self);
  AField.FieldName := 'CityID';
  AField.DataSet := cdsClients;

  cdsClients.CreateDataSet;
  cdsClients.InsertRecord([1, 'Client1']);
  cdsClients.InsertRecord([2, 'Client2']);
  cdsClients.InsertRecord([3, 'Client3']);
  cdsClients.First;

  DBLookUpComboBox1.DataSource := dsClients;
  DBLookUpComboBox1.ListSource := dsCities;
  DBLookUpComboBox1.DataField := 'CityID';
  DBLookUpComboBox1.ListField := 'CityName';
  DBLookUpComboBox1.KeyField := 'CityID';
end;

procedure TForm1.DBLookupComboBox1KeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if Key = VK_Return then
    if cdsClients.State in [dsEdit, dsInsert] then
      cdsClients.Post;
end;
```